# Find the points of continuity and discontinuity.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$f(x)=\frac{1}{q},\; \;\; x=\frac{p}{q}\in[0,1], p,q \in \mathbb{Z}^+$
and

$f(x)=0,\;\;\; otherwise.$

Find the points of continuity and discontinuity.

Answer to the above question is:

> $f$ is continuous at every irrational number in $[0,1]$ and $0$ but discontinuous at all rationals except $0$.

I know that if we can find two sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\} \in [0,1]$ such that $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ converges to $\alpha$ but $f(a_n),f(b_n)$ converges to different limits. Then $f$ is not continuous at $x=\alpha$.

I am unable to solve this. How to solve such question? Thanks.

Comment: Presumably in the definition of $f$ we assume $p,q$ relatively prime?

Comment: Your knowledge about sequences helps you to confirm that it is discontinuous at rationals except $0$.

Comment: This is called Tomae Function and it’s in wilkipedia. Just google it.

Comment: Yes. $p,q$ are relatively prime. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You know where $f$ is continuous and discontinuous. You have correctly stated a recipe for proving discontinuity of $f$ at a certain point. Where exactly are you stuck after this?

Comment: The solution is known (given at the end of the book), recipe is known. But I am unable to prove it i.e. how to prove/show this explicitly.

Comment: Another property you need here is following : Given any real number $\alpha$ and any positive integer $n$, there is a neighborhood $I$ of $\alpha$ such that if $x\in\mathbb {Q} \cap I, x\neq \alpha$ then $x$ has denominator greater than $n$. Understand and prove it. Then you can deal with continuity at irrationals.